# How to find all quarter start and end date for the provided date range

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my actual data

| ID | StartDateTime | EndDateTime | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2024-01-01 | 2024-06-30 | 14.00 |
| 2 | 2024-07-01 | 2024-12-30 | 10.00 |

Expected output

| ID | StartDateTime | EndDateTime | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2024-01-01 | 2024-03-31 | 14.00 |
| 1 | 2024-04-01 | 2024-06-30 | 14.00 |
| 2 | 2024-07-01 | 2024-09-30 | 10.00 |
| 2 | 2024-10-01 | 2024-12-30 | 10.00 |

Tried this but this will start with second quarter

```sql
with cte as (
      select id, start_date, num_quarters
      from t
      union all
      select id, dateadd(month, 3, start_date), num_quarters - 1
      from cte
      where num_quarters > 1
     )
select *
from cte;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On SQL Server 2022, you can use a combination of `DATETRUNC()`, `DATEDIFF()`, `GENERATE_SERIES()`, and `DATEADD()` to generate the quarters. The functions `LEAST()` and `GREATEST()` can then be applied to trim the first and last quarters to the original range (such as in your `'2024-12-30'` end date case. No CTEs are needed.

Logic:

1. The `DATEDIFF()` calculates the number of quarters needed - 1. If the original date range starts and ends in the same quarter, the quarter difference will be zero.
2. `GENERATE_SERIES()` generates a range of numbers 0..N.
3. `DATETRUNC()` is used to calculate the base date from which quarter start and end dates will be calculated.
4. `DATEADD()` then calculates these dates. The quarter-end date is calculated by adding an extra quarter and subtracting a day.
5. The `LEAST()` and `GREATEST()` can then be applied to trim the first and last quarters to the original range.

```
SELECT T.ID, D.StartDateTime, D.EndDateTime, T.Price
FROM Data T
CROSS APPLY GENERATE_SERIES(0, DATEDIFF(quarter, T.StartDateTime, T.EndDateTime)) S
CROSS APPLY (SELECT DATETRUNC(quarter, T.StartDateTime) AS QStart) Q
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT
        GREATEST(
            DATEADD(quarter, S.value, Q.QStart),
            T.StartDateTime
            ) AS StartDateTime,
        LEAST(
            DATEADD(day, -1, DATEADD(quarter, S.value + 1, Q.QStart)),
            T.EndDateTime
            ) AS EndDateTime
) D
ORDER BY T.ID, D.StartDateTime
```

Results (with some extra test data):

| ID | StartDateTime | EndDateTime | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2024-01-01 | 2024-03-31 | 14.00 |
| 1 | 2024-04-01 | 2024-06-30 | 14.00 |
| 2 | 2024-07-01 | 2024-09-30 | 10.00 |
| 2 | 2024-10-01 | 2024-12-30 | 10.00 |
| 3 | 2023-11-15 | 2023-12-31 | 88.00 |
| 3 | 2024-01-01 | 2024-03-31 | 88.00 |
| 3 | 2024-04-01 | 2024-06-30 | 88.00 |
| 3 | 2024-07-01 | 2024-08-14 | 88.00 |
| 4 | 2024-07-15 | 2024-08-14 | 99.00 |

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/1YIF2sYk).

Answer (score -1):

I solved this by using CTE

```
    ;WITH [CTE] AS (
                            SELECT
                                [ID],
                                [Price]                         
                                [StartDateTime],
                                -- Quarter end date for the current quarter start date
                                CONVERT(DATETIME,DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEADD(QUARTER, DATEDIFF(q, 0, StartDateTime) +1, 0))) AS [EndDateTime],                         
                                [EndDateTime] As [FinalEndDate]
                            FROM MyTable 
        
                            UNION ALL
    
                            SELECT
                                [ID],                           
                                [Price],
                                -- Next quarter start date
                                DATEADD(day, 1, CONVERT(DATETIME,DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEADD(QUARTER, DATEDIFF(q, 0, [StartDateTime]) +1, 0)))) AS [StartDateTime],
                                -- Next quarter end  date
                                CONVERT(DATETIME,DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEADD(QUARTER, DATEDIFF(QUARTER, 0, (DATEADD(day, 1, CONVERT(DATETIME,DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEADD(QUARTER, DATEDIFF(q, 0, [StartDateTime]) +1, 0)))))) +1, 0))) AS [EndDateTime],
                                
                                [FinalEndDate]       
                            FROM [CTE] WHERE  [FinalEndDate] > [EndDateTime]
                    )
        SELECT *
        FROM CTE;
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**